# How do people decide which political party is good for them?

Tags: india, political-system

There are 2 main political parties [Congress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_National_Congress) and [BJP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bharatiya_Janata_Party). Right now the situation becomes worse. Social media became boring - if I open Facebook and check I see lots of post regarding political things. It seems the whole Indian community is divided in two: Hindus and Muslims.

Hindus appear to think they are victimized, no one taking care of them and Muslims appear to think they are victimized and the current government is treating them unjust.

In such situation as a person not supporting any of the parties how can one decide if a party will become worthy for him as well as country?

Comment: I tried my best to fix some grammar in your post. Anyway, this seems rather broad and/or primarily opinion based. You should edit and try to make your post more specific (ask about certain points from their political platform).

Comment: @Alexei, I'll try to do the same

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, ignore political posts on social media.

Those messages which spread the widest on social media are those which have the most emotional impact. Not those which are the most objectively relevant. So if you get most of your political news from social media, then you will mostly read about irrelevant anecdotes and niche issues which make some people angry. You won't read much about the "boring" big picture topics which affect everyone in the long run but are not as emotionally charged.

Also, few people bother to fact-check things they share on social media. The result is that many social media users (intentionally or unintentionally) spread misinformation.

If you want to know which party actually stands for what, then there are two important things.

1. what they say
2. what they do

When it comes to what they say, do not rely on second hand reporting. Look what they themselves are saying. When you see some news "Politician X said outrageous thing Y", find out what the context of that quote was and what they actually meant with it. For example, when you see outrage on social media because a politician apparently said "All Pastafari must die!", your research might reveal that what they actually said was "All Pastafari must die one day, and so do people of other religions, because we are all mortal beings with a limited time on this world, which is why we need an inheritance tax reform".

When it's election season, parties will publish their election manifests on their websites. Before you cast your vote, you should read the manifests of all relevant parties. There will always be some parts you disagree with. What matters most is which party you agree with the most on the core issues you consider the most important.

But politicians also tend to promise one thing and then do another. So a far more important thing to check is what they actually do.

1. Look up some [bills which were recently passed in the Lok Sabha and Rajya Sabha](http://164.100.47.194/Loksabha/Legislation/billspassed.aspx)
2. Find out what they actually mean (the hardest part)
3. Check who proposed them and which party they are from
4. Check which parties voted for them and which voted against them

Understanding a bill is often the hardest part, but also the most educational. It is often not obvious at first glance which segments of the population are affected by it and what exactly the short term and long term effects will be. In order to understand this, you need to educate yourself about the socioeconomic backgrounds and how the bill interacts with other laws. This can seem quite dull and boring if compared to the funny pictures on Facebook and the lurid slogans on Twitter. But it will help you to go beneath the shouting of the populists and understand what is actually going on in your country.

Comment: Yep, this make sense.

Comment: Great post, @Philipp!  Thank you!  I wanted to chime in, _3. When they say it._  In US elections we have an expectation that during primaries, candidates will try to gain support from vocal minority groups; while during general elections, those same candidates will try to distance themselves from vocal minorities and "turn toward the center".  This is a matter of character and integrity and it would be unfortunate for an unseasoned voting bloc to be blindsided by this annoying pattern.

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of country there are a few other factors that factor into this that most people seem to overlook:

1) Who your parents voted for, and what your overall family believes in regards to politics. Since you are impressionable as a child, you can become swayed one way, purely because that's what you were raised with, and may not actually be your own decision.

2) What your economic situation is. People who are more wealthy will vote for people who will maintain their wealth and not steal it through taxes and such. While poorer people will often vote for freebies and benefits to get them out of poverty.

Feel free to disagree, but these are definetly biases that most overlook when it comes to how people decide what political party is who they stand behind.